Access Kotlin class from Jakara Faces 4.0 XHTML
I had been using Kotlin (1.4.10) with JSF (XHTML) on WildFly (15.x -> 20.x) successfully to ~December 2018. Using Java EE (8) with JSF.
I'm now migrating an existing working Jakarta (Java) EE (10.0.0 & 11.0.0-M2) using simple Jakarta Faces (4.0) on WildFly (32.0.0.Final) with 'standalone.xml' on Mojarra (4.0.7) to Kotlin (1.9.23 & 2.0.0.RC1).
XHTML:
<f:view>
    <h:body>
        <p:dataTable value="#{usersKotlinController.allUsers}"
                     lazy="true"
                     style="width:100%"
                     var="usersKotlin"
                     rowKey="#{usersKotlin.id}"
                     border="1"
                     headerText="Kotlin Users"
                     scrollable="false">

            <p:column width="100%" visible="true">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Kotlin Users"/>
                </f:facet>

                <h:outputText value="#{usersKotlin.mobile}">
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
    </h:body>
</f:view>

kt Controller:
@Named("usersKotlinController")
open class UsersKotlinController : Serializable {
    @Inject
    private lateinit var usersKotlinEJB: UsersKotlinEJB

    fun getAllUsers(): List<UsersKotlin> {
        println("***** 1.1 fun getAllUsers(): List<UsersKotlin")

        val usersKotlinList: List<UsersKotlin> = usersKotlinEJB.getAllUsers()

        println("***** 1.2 UserKotlinEJB usersKotlinList = " + usersKotlinList)
        println("***** 1.3 UserKotlinEJB usersKotlinList size = " + usersKotlinList.size)

        return usersKotlinList
    }
    companion object {
        /**
         *
         */
        private const val serialVersionUID = 1L

        /**
         *
         */
        private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}
    }
}

kt EJB:
@Stateless
open class UsersKotlinEJB {
    val datastoreBeWhereWhen: Datastore = Morphia.createDatastore(MongoClients.create(), "beWhereWhenDB")

    open fun getAllUsers(): List<com.bewherewhen.kotlin.entity.morphia.users.UsersKotlin> {
        val usersQuery = datastoreBeWhereWhen.find(com.bewherewhen.kotlin.entity.morphia.users.UsersKotlin::class.java)
        println("***** 2.1 UserKotlinEJB usersQuery = " + usersQuery)

        val usersList: List<com.bewherewhen.kotlin.entity.morphia.users.UsersKotlin> = usersQuery.iterator().toList()
        println("***** 2.2 UserKotlinEJB usersList size = " + usersList.size)

        return usersList
    }
}

kt Entity:
@Entity
data class UsersKotlin(
    @Id
    val id: ObjectId?,

    var mobile: String? = null,
    var email: String? = null,
    var salutation: String? = null,
    var title: String? = null,
    var forename: String? = null,
    var surname: String? = null,
    var house_name_number: String? = null,
    var post_code_zip: String? = null,
    var dateStart: Date? = null,

    @Reference
    var myEventDateKotlins: List<MyEventDatesKotlin> // etc ...
)

Starts & 'Runs' on WildFly:
 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'UsersKotlinEJB' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "BeWhereWhenJAR.jar" of deployment "BeWhereWhen.ear"' are as follows:
    
        java:global/BeWhereWhen/BeWhereWhenJAR/UsersKotlinEJB!com.bewherewhen.kotlin.ejb.UsersKotlinEJB
        java:app/BeWhereWhenJAR/UsersKotlinEJB!com.bewherewhen.kotlin.ejb.UsersKotlinEJB
        java:module/UsersKotlinEJB!com.bewherewhen.kotlin.ejb.UsersKotlinEJB
        java:global/BeWhereWhen/BeWhereWhenJAR/UsersKotlinEJB
        java:app/BeWhereWhenJAR/UsersKotlinEJB
        java:module/UsersKotlinEJB
    
  INFO  [jakarta.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.faces.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 89) Initializing Mojarra 4.0.6 for context '/BeWhereWhen'
  INFO  [jakarta.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.faces.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 89) Monitoring file:/usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/wildfly-32.0.0.Beta1/standalone/tmp/vfs/deployment/deployment8f76f3833e8a1aba/BeWhereWhenWAR.war-b52a211bf32ce343/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
  INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 89) Running on PrimeFaces 13.0.8
  INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 89) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/BeWhereWhen' for server 'default-server'
  INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "BeWhereWhen.ear" (runtime-name : "BeWhereWhen.ear")

When I run my 'localhost:8080/BeWhereWhen' it displays the page but none of the logs are displayed on my Kotlin "Controller". It is though :
open class UsersKotlinController : Serializable {

is ignored. No errors.
My tech. spec:

WildFly Distribution (standalone.xml) - 32.0.0.Final
Jakarta EE 10.0.0 & 11.0.0-M2
JDK 21.0.2 & 22.0.1
Kotlin 2.0.0
Gradle 8.8
Jakarta Faces 4.0.1
Morphia 2.4.13 (MongoDB Object Document Mapping)
Mojarra 4.0.7
macOS Sonoma 14.5

I have looked at:
Enterprise Kotlin: Kotlin and Jakarta EE
Baeldung Michal Aibin: Java EE Application with Kotlin
Anyone able to use Kotlin 1.9.x & Jakara Faces 4.0 on Mojarra?
[#2]
Just upgraded Kotlin to 2.0.0-RC3:
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:2.0.0-RC3")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-allopen:2.0.0-RC3")

First noticed "WELD-000119: Not generating any bean":
INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 2) WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from com.bewherewhen.kotlin.controller.UsersKotlinController because of underlying class loading error: Type io.github.oshai.kotlinlogging.KLogger from [Module "deployment.BeWhereWhenKt.ear.BeWhereWhenKtJAR.jar" from Service Module Loader] not found.

If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.

Set WildFly: Subsystems | Logging | Configuration | Level | DEBUG: no  errors ... only INFO & WARN (x3)
WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.elytron] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYELY00023: KeyStore file '/usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/wildfly-32.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration/application.keystore' does not exist. Used blank.
WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.elytron] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYELY01084: KeyStore /usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/wildfly-32.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto-generated on first use with a self-signed certificate for host localhost

WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0131: Jakarta Enterprise Beans com.bewherewhen.kotlin.ejb.UsersKotlinEJB should not have a final or static method (getDatastoreBeWhereWhen)

[#3]
Have converted working Java code (using IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.2 Ultimate EditionJ) to Kotlin 2.0.
My EAR won't deploy on WildFly 32.0.0.Final:
10:28:12,027 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment BeWhereWhenWAR.war
10:28:12,086 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) WELD-000900: 5.1.2 (Final)
10:28:12,361 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."BeWhereWhen.ear".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."BeWhereWhen.ear".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.4.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1609)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.4.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1438)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000810: Cannot place qualifiers on final fields:  [EnhancedAnnotatedFieldImpl] @Inject private final com.bewherewhen.kotlin.controller.EventsMeetingsSocialControllerKt.eventsMeetingsSocialEJBKt
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionPointFactory.addFieldInjectionPoint(InjectionPointFactory.java:229)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionPointFactory.getFieldInjectionPoints(InjectionPointFactory.java:215)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.<init>(DefaultInjector.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.<init>(ResourceInjector.java:57)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.of(ResourceInjector.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.<init>(BeanInjectionTarget.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.createDefault(BeanInjectionTarget.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.chooseInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.<init>(ManagedBean.java:105)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.of(ManagedBean.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.createManagedBean(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:284)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.createClassBean(BeanDeployer.java:284)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:69)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)

10:28:12,364 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "BeWhereWhen.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"BeWhereWhen.ear\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000810: Cannot place qualifiers on final fields:  [EnhancedAnnotatedFieldImpl] @Inject private final com.bewherewhen.kotlin.controller.EventsMeetingsSocialControllerKt.eventsMeetingsSocialEJBKt"}}
10:28:12,364 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "BeWhereWhen.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"BeWhereWhen.ear\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000810: Cannot place qualifiers on final fields:  [EnhancedAnnotatedFieldImpl] @Inject private final com.bewherewhen.kotlin.controller.EventsMeetingsSocialControllerKt.eventsMeetingsSocialEJBKt"}}
10:28:12,365 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "BeWhereWhen.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"BeWhereWhen.ear\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000810: Cannot place qualifiers on final fields:  [EnhancedAnnotatedFieldImpl] @Inject private final com.bewherewhen.kotlin.controller.EventsMeetingsSocialControllerKt.eventsMeetingsSocialEJBKt"}}

and:
10:50:41,805 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."BeWhereWhen.ear".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."BeWhereWhen.ear".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.4.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1609)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.4.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1438)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000810: Cannot place qualifiers on final fields:  [EnhancedAnnotatedFieldImpl] @Inject private final com.bewherewhen.kotlin.controller.EventsMeetingsSocialControllerKt.eventsMeetingsSocialEJBKt
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionPointFactory.addFieldInjectionPoint(InjectionPointFactory.java:229)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionPointFactory.getFieldInjectionPoints(InjectionPointFactory.java:215)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.<init>(DefaultInjector.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.<init>(ResourceInjector.java:57)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.of(ResourceInjector.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.<init>(BeanInjectionTarget.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.createDefault(BeanInjectionTarget.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.chooseInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.<init>(ManagedBean.java:105)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.of(ManagedBean.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.createManagedBean(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:284)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.createClassBean(BeanDeployer.java:284)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:69)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)

10:50:41,807 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "BeWhereWhen.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"BeWhereWhen.ear\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000810: Cannot place qualifiers on final fields:  [EnhancedAnnotatedFieldImpl] @Inject private final com.bewherewhen.kotlin.controller.EventsMeetingsSocialControllerKt.eventsMeetingsSocialEJBKt"}}
10:50:41,807 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "BeWhereWhen.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"BeWhereWhen.ear\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000810: Cannot place qualifiers on final fields:  [EnhancedAnnotatedFieldImpl] @Inject private final com.bewherewhen.kotlin.controller.EventsMeetingsSocialControllerKt.eventsMeetingsSocialEJBKt"}}
10:50:41,807 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "BeWhereWhen.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"BeWhereWhen.ear\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000810: Cannot place qualifiers on final fields:  [EnhancedAnnotatedFieldImpl] @Inject private final com.bewherewhen.kotlin.controller.EventsMeetingsSocialControllerKt.eventsMeetingsSocialEJBKt"}}

Anyone aware of the issue with WELD? TIA.

Fields cannot be final for injection as injection happens after the class is created.

@James R. Perkins Thanks. I was using Kotlin together with EE/WildFly prior to Jarkarta (see above). What has changed with WELD since then?

Nothing should have changed in that regard. Fields have never been able to be final unless you inject in the constructor.

Fixed my migrating of Java to Kotlin. The issue caused by 'Fields cannot be final for injection as injection'. As '@James R. Perkins' commented with a "Fields cannot be final for injection as injection".
Added 'lateinit var' to 'Controller':
@Named("eventsMeetingsSocialControllerKt")
@RequestScoped
open class EventsMeetingsSocialControllerKt {

    private lateinit var eventsMeetingsSocialList: List<com.bewherewhen.kotlin.entity.morphia.EventsMeetingsSocial>

    @Inject
    private lateinit var eventsMeetingsSocialEJBKt: EventsMeetingsSocialEJBKt
    ...
}

Added 'lateinit var' to 'EJB':
@Stateless
@LocalBean
open class EventsMeetingsSocialEJBKt {
   ...
  private lateinit var eventsMeetingsSocialsLists: 
  List<EventsMeetingsSocial>

    open fun allEventsMeetingsSocial(): List<EventsMeetingsSocial> {

        val eventsMeetingsSocialQuery =
            datastoreBeWhereWhen.find(EventsMeetingsSocial::class.java)

        eventsMeetingsSocialQuery.iterator().toList()
        eventsMeetingsSocialsLists = eventsMeetingsSocialQuery.iterator().toList()
        ...
    }
}

'Serializable' the Entity:
@Entity(value = "eventsMeetingsSocial", useDiscriminator = false)
@Indexes(Index(options = IndexOptions(name = "eventsMeetingsSocial")))
class EventsMeetingsSocial : Serializable {
   ...
}

Displayed on Terminal with WildFly:
INFO  [org.mongodb.driver.cluster] (cluster-ClusterId{value='6661d00b2cab0c1c84295dad', description='null'}-localhost:27017) Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=21, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=408750}
INFO  [com.bewherewhen.kotlin.ejb.EventsMeetingsSocialEJBKt] (default task-1) ***** 8.1 EventsMeetingsSocial eventsMeetingsSocialsLists = 5
INFO  [com.bewherewhen.kotlin.controller.EventsMeetingsSocialControllerKt] (default task-1) ***** 7.1 eventsMeetingsSocialKtEJB.getAllEventsMeetingsSocial size = 5
INFO  [com.bewherewhen.kotlin.controller.EventsMeetingsSocialControllerKt] (default task-1) ***** 7.2 eventsMeetingsSocialJtEJB.getAllEventsMeetingsSocial = [EventsMeetingsSocialKotlin{eventsMeetingsSocial='Friends'}, EventsMeetingsSocialKotlin{eventsMeetingsSocial='Family'}, EventsMeetingsSocialKotlin{eventsMeetingsSocial='Colleague'}, EventsMeetingsSocialKotlin{eventsMeetingsSocial='Neighbours'}, EventsMeetingsSocialKotlin{eventsMeetingsSocial='Acquaintances'}]

